# Invoke-command very slow

Tags: multithreading, powershell, performance

I have a PS script with invoke-command.
I want to update the value if I haven't retrieved anything for that machine before.

This command takes long time. We have about 10000 computers inside computers CSV file.

Invoke-Command -ComputerName accepts an array of computers

How can I speed up the this script?

Here is my script :

```
$computers = Import-Csv "C:\temp\computers.csv"

$AllResults = foreach ($computer in $computers) {
    try {
      if (($computer.Appx -eq 'Port closed or computer unreachable') -Or ($null -eq $computer.Appx)){
       Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computer.name -ScriptBlock { Get-AppxPackage -AllUsers } -ErrorAction 'Stop' | ForEach-Object {
        [pscustomobject]@{
            "ComputerName" = $computer.Name
            "Appx"         = $_.Name -join ";"
          }
        }
      }
    }
    catch {
        [pscustomobject]@{
            "ComputerName" = $computer.Name
            "Appx"         = "Port closed or computer unreachable"
        }
    }
}

$AllResults | Export-Csv -Path "C:\Temp\MSStoreReport.csv" -NoTypeInformation -Encoding 'UTF8'
```

Comment: The best way is to splits the csv file task in parallel.  The would mean the output file would also be split.  Better would be to use a database that contains the csv data and results.  Use a database that is multi-threaded like SQL Server.

Comment: Simple way to go parallel: create a script that queries local computer and generates csv, then copies results to network share. Push that script on computers. Invoke it with Task Scheduler and combine the results later.

Comment: `invoke-command $computers { script... }` would run in parallel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [PowerShell 7](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell) and the [`Foreach-Object -Parallel`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object#-parallel) cmdlet parameter:

```
Import-Csv "C:\temp\computers.csv" |Foreach-Object -Parallel {
    $Computer = $_
    try {
      if (($Computer.Appx -eq 'Port closed or computer unreachable') -Or ($null -eq $Computer.Appx)){
       Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Computer.Name -ScriptBlock { Get-AppxPackage -AllUsers } -ErrorAction 'Stop' | ForEach-Object {
        [pscustomobject]@{
            "ComputerName" = $Computer.Name
            "Appx"         = $_.Name -join ";"
          }
        }
      }
    }
    catch {
        [pscustomobject]@{
            "ComputerName" = $Computer.Name
            "Appx"         = "Port closed or computer unreachable"
        }
    }
} |Export-Csv -Path "C:\Temp\MSStoreReport.csv" -Encoding 'UTF8'
```

You might want to play with the [`-ThrottleLimit`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object#-throttlelimit) parameter to define howmany threads/remote computers you want to handle in parallel.

Comment: thanks. btw , invoke-command is multi-threaded out of the box. I believe invoke-command uses a default throttlelimit of 25.

Comment: *invoke-command is multi-threaded out of the box*, I guess you're right (you can start a background job with `-AsJob`) but that would require to check each job/computer status whether it is ready before retrieving the results. In your initial script you're running each job in a sequence as you wait for each job/computer to return its result before continuing with the next job/computer. `Foreach-Object -Parallel` will handle this invocation/retrieving in each thread and put the results on the pipeline a whole.

Comment: thanks again lastly I have a different question.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76065787/updating-input-csv-file-based-on-server-status